# Is there anything special about Git feature branches?

Tags: git, branch, git-flow

I'm trying to understand **feature** branches in `git`. My understanding is that the term *feature branch* is simply a naming convention or methodology to help conceptualize and organize when add new code.

Specifically, my understanding is:

- Prefixing a branch name with `feature/` is just a convention (in contrast to say `origin/` which has meaning)
- There is nothing inherently *special* about creating a branch called `feature/what-ever-my-new-feature-is`
- It does not restrict how/where that branch can be merged with any other branch
- One can still merge a `feature/` with any other branch, regardless of where it was initially branched from (e.g. directly to `master`)

Am I failing to grasp something fundamental?

Comment: no nothing special about feature branches, they are like normal git branches, the only thing is that are going to add new feature to application and hence are called feature branches

Comment: You are correct, all branch names are (mostly) meaningless and are just named by convention. The only time the branch name could *actually* matter is to things like CM/CI. For example you can set up BitBucket to *only* allow pull requests from `feature/` branches to `release/` branches or whatever. Similarly you could have things like Jenkins or TeamCity *only* pick up `feature/` branches for automated build triggers. So in those cases the names do matter a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The use of git "feature" branches is more about communicating in a consistent way when working with a team of developers.

Two common branching strategies that make use of feature branches are [GitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) and [Trunk](https://paulhammant.com/2013/04/05/what-is-trunk-based-development/).  You can dig in to them a bit and see how they may be helpful to your development workflow.

As @CoryKramer mentioned, prefixing branches with a standard prefix (ie. Feature, Hotfix, Release, etc) is most helpful for automating your development process with continuous integration tools like Jenkins, Bamboo, CircleCI, TravisCI, etc. A common practice is to spawn builds for specific feature branches and prevent merging to master until the feature has successfully built, been code reviewed, and has proper test coverage.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that using a `feature/` branch _does_ in fact, affect and organize your folder structure different inside `.git/refs/heads/feature` but whether that adds anything to the casual user is beyond me.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the differences in how git organizes prefixed branches under the hood so I can't help there.  The behavior for merges is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what's written, I would add one thing:  You mention that a "branch name" starting with `origin/` is special; but this isn't exactly right.

`origin/master` is *not* a branch with a special name.  The `origin/master` you typically see is actually `refs/remotes/origin/master` - a remote branch reference, which is a different thing from a branch.  (A branch is a type of ref, and so with the similar words flying around it's a little confusing.  But a branch is a ref that, by default, moves when you commit while it's checked out.  A remote branch ref is a ref that, by default, moves as needed during communication with the corresponding remote.)

(If you had a branch named `origin/master`, that would be `refs/heads/origin/master`, and in that case the `origin/` prefix would be meaningless, just like any other.  But a word of advice: don't do that. It'll only lead to confusion.)